# Difference between next-auth token rotation and axios interceptor token rotation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Im developing a nextjs application and for authentication im using next-auth.
Next auth provides refresh token mechanism
https://authjs.dev/guides/basics/refresh-token-rotation

but when it comes to making api calls for a private route in the app is it better to write axios interceptor to handle token rotation since next-auth token rotation runs only on page mount? Is my understanding about the next-auth token rotation mechanism correct?

When I implemented next-auth token rotation and called a private api route, if the token was expired it didnt get replaced by calling the getaccesstoken route